# Difficulty running external executable using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script to iterate through folders in a directory and run the same .exe in each sub-directory (The same process hundreds of times). The .exe is called *aermod.exe* and I typically run it by simply double-clicking (no DOS inputs).

My code below is giving me an input file run stream error and I think it is related to not calling the .exe correctly.

Any thoughts?

```py
import os
import subprocess
    
rootdir = os.getcwd()
    
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for dir in dirs:
        print(dir)
        print(rootdir)
        executable = os.path.join(rootdir + "\\" + dir + "\\" 'aermod' )
        subprocess.call(executable)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we can see the exact error.

Comment: You likely want `subprocess.call([executable], cwd=os.path.join(subdir, dir))`

Comment: `rootdir` isn't actually where `dir` is located, if your `os.walk()` recursed more than one level deep - you want to use `subdir`, instead.  Also, the proper use is `os.path.join(subdir, dir, 'aermod')` - concatenating the pieces yourself entirely defeats the point of that function.

Comment: Have you tried using bat file for this purpose??

Comment: Missing + sign before ‘aermod’